# bandwidth monitoring issue on PfSense router

Tags: freebsd, bandwidth, pfsense, traffic-management

I have a PfSense router installed , where it has 4 interfaces.
one of them is WAN and rest 3 are LAN networks, which have different subnets and IP address ranges.

wan interface name = em0
lan interfaces names = em1 em2 em3

i have used PfSense traffic graphs module, which only shows bandwidth usage on just one interface.

Issue is that how can i get the bandwidth usage of ALL the LAN ip hosts? (and this bandwidth usage should not only of WAN traffic or the traffic that passed from wan interface.
for example, if there is inter-Lan communication, then using the already present traffic monitoring tools, i can see that certain hosts on interface em2 are using very high bandwidth, but that bandwidth is between Lan hosts, not of Wan. (some of it is to/from wan).

So is there any way that i can separate the LAN bandwidth usage from WAN bandwidth usage? so that i can see EXACT Wan bandwidth usage of each host connected to PfSense?

(My PfSense router is using squid, so i can get the bandwsith usage of HTTP/HTTPS traffic, but i need to know the traffic usage of Every post, not just HTTP or HTTPS.)

FYI, the WAN interface is in NAT with the Lan side.

Comment: May I ask how did you configured your squid on PfSense to monitor HTTPS ?

Comment: No, i have not configured https. sorry, i mistakenly wrote HTTPS there. but i really want to have HTTPS with squid on pfsense, dont know why they have not implemented it yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of options. 
http://doc.pfsense.org/index.php/How_can_I_monitor_bandwidth_usage%3F

Answer (score 0):

The **Traffic Graph** module is pretty good for realtime throughput monitoring between the LAN interface and internal hosts, showing realtime usage per host.  The other packages mentioned in the pfsense doc are better for longer term stats per host.

Comment: i need to know both upload and download, but traffic graphs only sorts the usage based on Download. and the more interfaces i have, the more number of times i have to switch the views for each interface. makes it very hectic.

Comment: Traffic Graph on pfSense v2 shows both in and out throughput per IP address.  Also, it's still not clear if you are looking for real-time throughput or historical usage.

Comment: yes, i said the same, it actually Shows, but it Sorts them only on high download usage, not on upload.